# How does z-index impact the click area of an anchor element wrapping an <svg> element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've got three tabs on my page made by `<svg>` elements, all irregular shapes. Because I want the tabs to be clickable only on the relevant portions of the elements (as opposed to the whole box representing them, which includes whitespace), I've wrapped each of them with an `<a>` element.
As an example:

```
<svg id="recents-tab" ...>
   <a id="recents-tab-wrapper" class="svg-click-wrapper">

       <path ... >
       <circle ...>
       <path ... >
       <line ... >
            ...

   </a>
</svg>
```

Each  element is relatively positioned. I have styled all three to `cursor: grab` in the stylesheet, and when I hover over any of the relevant portions of all three tabs, I expect to see the cursor change. However, it only changes thoroughly when I hover over the `<svg>` element with the highest z-index. When I hover over the other, lower z-index tabs, the cursor doesn't change — except when I hover over the very top of those tabs, at the line where the top of the tab meets the white space above.

I have also tested this with the `onclick` event and I got the same result, which is why I suspect the problem lies in the click area.

Here's a visualization of the three tabs.

[image: tabs]

Comment: We need to see some css. You should only need to use z-index in certain circumstances, but can you share more code, do you have an example?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the remaining of the `<svg>` still does capture pointer events.

Here is a minimal example where I made the `<svg>`'s background green so that you see the `<svg>` elements do overlap (the result is the same with or without the background color).

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: rgba(125, 255, 0, 0.8);
  margin-right: -150px;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
Try to mouse over the circles.<br>
<svg><a><circle cx=150 cy=50 r=30 /></a></svg>
<svg><a><circle cx=150 cy=50 r=30 /></a></svg>
<svg><a><circle cx=150 cy=50 r=30 /></a></svg>
```

Not seeing your exact markup it's hard to say what's wrong with your code, but if you can't reach anything from the elements that are below, you probably want to tweak their `viewBox`, `width`, and `height` attributes so that the element doesn't take more space than needed.

But even then, you can set your `<svg>` `pointer-events` CSS attribute to `none`, and set the inner's `<a>` one to `all` so that it listens only for where you have visible shapes:

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: rgba(125, 255, 0, 0.8);
  margin-right: -150px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
Try to mouse over the circles.<br>
<svg><a><circle cx=150 cy=50 r=30 /></a></svg>
<svg><a><circle cx=150 cy=50 r=30 /></a></svg>
<svg><a><circle cx=150 cy=50 r=30 /></a></svg>
```